# How to get marker popup on hover element from list using Leaflet and L.Control.ListMarkers?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

Using Leaflet and plugins like [ListMarkers](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-list-markers), I display a list of visible markers on the map. After hovering over the appropriate `<li>` element in the List, I want the marker popup to be displayed. The `<li>` element contains various information about the product, unfortunately after hovering over them, the popup appears and disappears. How to make it that if I hover entire `<li>` element popup will show and not go crazy of each element separately ?

```
        var list = new L.Control.ListMarkers({ layer: markers, itemIcon: null });
            list.addTo(map);

            list.on('item-mouseover', function(e) {
                e.layer.setIcon(L.icon({
                    iconUrl: '/marker2.png'
                }));
                e.layer.openPopup();
            }).on('item-mouseout', function(e) {
                e.layer.setIcon(L.icon({
                    iconUrl: '/marker.png'
                }))
                e.layer.closePopup();
            });

            listaHTML = list.getContainer();

            document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(listaHTML);
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a CSS problem.

**Workaround**

```
li.list-markers-li>a>span,
li.list-markers-li>a>b {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```js
var map = new L.Map('map', {
  zoom: 10,
  minZoom: 10,
  center: L.latLng(43.90974, 10.2419)
});

map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')); //base layer

var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup(); //layer contain searched elements
map.addLayer(markersLayer);

////////////populate map from cities-italy.js
for (var i in cities) {
  let marker = L.marker(L.latLng(cities[i].loc), {
    title: cities[i].name
  }).addTo(markersLayer);

  marker.bindPopup(cities[i].name)
}

var list = new L.Control.ListMarkers({
  layer: markersLayer,
  itemIcon: null
});

list.on('item-mouseover', function(e) {
  e.layer.openPopup();
}).on('item-mouseout', function(e) {
  e.layer.closePopup();
});

map.addControl(list);
```

```css
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%
}

li.list-markers-li>a>span,
li.list-markers-li>a>b {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-list-markers/examples/cities-italy.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<script src="https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-list-markers/src/leaflet-list-markers.js"></script>
<link href="https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-list-markers/src/leaflet-list-markers.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I got to the same place, everything works fine but unfortunately, the problem is when I am trying to mousover on text (like Lucca, Capannori) and than mouseout from the text, popup hide and show. I want to show popup when you mouseover on entire  .list-markers-li container and now hide when mouseover on text.

Comment: The problem does not occur on iOS.

Comment: Almost, but I have in this span links, which lead to product subpage. After adding pointer-events: none to spam, the links have stopped working

Comment: @mat could you made a fiddle with the links as you mentioned? So that I can help easily